# How to upgrade from MySQL 5.7 to 8.0 on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to upgrade my 5.7 MySQL database to 8.0, on Ubuntu 18.04.

Added the repositories,

```
wget https://repo.mysql.com//mysql-apt-config_0.8.10-1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.10-1_all.deb
```

Update and install:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

But it still tries to install version 5.7? I have tried various repositories and methods, but they all come down to 5.7?

Comment: Please follow the documentation at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-apt-repo-quick-guide/en/#repo-qg-apt-upgrading

BTW 8.0.10 is very old so please download the latest version

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue.

The following answer worked for me:
https://askubuntu.com/a/1122890/834996

The reason it was not working was due to the error mentioned there:

```
Err:1 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu bionic InRelease                        
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY <some key value>
```

And the solution is to add the key using:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys <key value>
```

After this, you continue with the steps mentioned there and MySQL 8 will be successfully installed.